# How to invoke a target of a msbuild project without recursively calling the same target on sub projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I created bunch of targets in msbuild project. Lets call this project TopLevelProject. Lets say this has a target called CollectNZip. TopLevelProject depends on SubProjectA, SubProjectB and SubProjectC.

I have a solutions targets file Directory.Solution.targets that contains all the projects below its folder including TopLevelProject.

As part of a target in this file say BuildAll, I like to invoke CollectNZip target of TopLevelProject. So I added TopLevelProject:CollectNZip as dependency.

When I invoke BuildAll, I do see TopLevelProject is invoked with target CollectNZip. But this sucker as part of dependency started invoking SubProjectA:CollectNZip, SubProjectB:CollectNZip etc. As those sub projects don't have CollectNZip, the buildall target is failing.

What is the trick to invoke a target of a project, but don't invoke the sub projects as part of the invocation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the scenario:

- There is a solution file with a set of projects. Let's say the solution is named 'MySolution.sln'.
- I assume the solution file was created by either Visual Studio or the dotnet tool.
- The set of projects in the solution include: 'TopLevelProject.csproj', 'SubProjectA.csproj', 'SubProjectB.csproj', and 'SubProjectC.csproj'.
- I assume the project files were created as C# projects by either Visual Studio or the dotnet tool.
- The project 'TopLevelProject' has `ProjectReference`s to 'SubProjectA', 'SubProjectB', and 'SubProjectC'.
- The project 'TopLevelProject' also has a target named 'CollectNZip'.
- There is a 'Directory.Solution.targets' file that is a peer of 'MySolution.sln' or in a parent directory.
- 'Directory.Solution.targets' contains a 'BuildAll` target.

The 'Directory.Solution.targets' file is ignored by Visual Studio so the 'BuildAll' target is only available when running from the command line.

Projects can be added to a solution file (SLN) but can't be added to an MSBuild file. The 'Directory.Solution.targets' file is an MSBuild file. It can't be a container for projects. I don't know what the following statement means:

> I have a solutions targets file Directory.Solution.targets that contains all the projects below its folder including TopLevelProject.

Note that the `Import` element is a textual include. It doesn't "add" a project; it adds the content of the file in the `Project` attribute into the content of the current project.

From the command line, you can invoke the 'CollectNZip' target of project 'TopLevelProject' via the solution file.

e.g.

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:TopLevelProject:CollectNZip
```

This will invoke only the 'CollectNZip' target on only the `TopLevelProject` project. It will not run other projects from the solution.

I don't know what the following statement means:

> As part of a target in this file say BuildAll, I like to invoke CollectNZip target of TopLevelProject. So I added TopLevelProject:CollectNZip as dependency.

The `<ProjectName>:<TargetName>` syntax is supported for the command line /target switch. It is not supported within the code of an MSBuild file. `TopLevelProject:CollectNZip` can't be a dependency of a target.

MSBuild doesn't have any notion of "sub projects" although there are two mechanisms which can add dependencies between projects.

A project dependency can be added to the solution file. The solution level project dependency effects the build order -- and does nothing else. It does not share files.

A `ProjectReference` can be added to a project file. The `ProjectReference` is an ItemGroup and is part of the C# project build system that is built on the general MSBuild build engine. `ProjectReference` is specific to certain targets of the C# build system, most importantly the `build` and `clean` targets. `build` and `clean` will evaluate the `ProjectReference` ItemGroup, will run the referenced projects, and on a `build` will copy in the product of the referenced project.

If I add a target named 'Fred' to all the projects and I invoke 'Fred' on one project via the solution, 'Fred' will not be called on projects in the `ProjectReference` ItemGroup.

A project is an encapsulation. It doesn't know its 'caller' and, excepting `ProjectReference`, it doesn't know about other projects.

The described behavior is not how MSBuild works and I'm guessing that the description is imprecise and/or there is pertinent code not shown.

If 'CollectNZip' should only run within the 'TopLevelProject' project, then only add the target to that project. If you want to be able to `build` with and without 'CollectNZip', define a property that can be used as a flag, e.g. add an 'EnableCollectNZip' property and add a `Condition` on the target that tests the value of the 'EnableCollectNZip' property.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for detailed response. I am afraid "msbuild MySolution.sln /t:TopLevelProject:CollectNZip" invokes that target on all sub projects. I have a solution with 150+ projects. I need time to create a sample solution to test this. Please stay tuned and happy holidays!

Comment: Does the `CollectNZip` target, or a target that `CollectNZip` depends on, contain an `MSBuild` task (or an `Exec` task) that is invoking the other projects? Thanks and happy holidays also!

Comment: CollectNZip is a target. It doesn't have msbuild task calls in it. It has copy and zip task calls instead.